# Bar graph values missing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
cols = ['hops','frequency']
data = [[-13,1],[-8,1],[-5,1],[0,2],[2,1],[4,1],[7,1]]
data = np.asarray(data)
indices = np.arange(0,len(data))

plot_data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=indices, columns=cols)

plt.bar(plot_data['hops'].tolist(),plot_data['frequency'].tolist(),width=0.8)
plt.xlim([-20,20])
plt.ylim([0,20])
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Hops')
```

Output-

[image]

My requirements-
I want the graph to have the scale X axis-[-20,20],Y axis [0,18] and the bars should be labelled like in this case the 1st bar should be numbered 1 in this case and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

Comment: "Bar graph values are missing": no, they're not: you have exactly the data you input in the figure. What is the issue? Is the code buggy? How does it not work? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You should be more clear in what you want. The reason your question is unanswered even after 13 hours is that it's hard to understand what you want. The "bar graph values missing" doesn't explain the problem. Where do you expect the values? Which values are missing? Do you want to annotate bars with individual values? Your bars are unequally spaced so putting 1,2,3,4.. as x ticklabels doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Bazingaa I want the x labels of my bars to have the values marked like the first bar should have the value -13 but still retaining the scale of x axis marked

Comment: -13 should be written on the top of the bar?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, I am assuming this is what you want. You just need to specify the positions at which you want the x-tick labels.

```
xtcks = [-20, 20]
plt.xticks(np.insert(xtcks, 1, data[:, 0]))
plt.yticks([0, 18])
```

[image]

Comment: I want to mark the x and y range too that is -20 20 andn 0 18 respectively

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you want